# Query to group all the rows with same column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

| userid | tenantid |
| --- | --- |
| null | a001 |
| null | a002 |
| null | a002 |
| null | a002 |
| null | a001 |
| null | a003 |
| null | a002 |
| null | a003 |
| null | a001 |
| null | a002 |

I want to  set the `userid` as "distinct_user_#" for the rows with same tenant ids. I can't set the `userid` manually as `tenantid`s are generated randomly

So output would be something like

| userid | tenantid |
| --- | --- |
| d_u_1 | a001 |
| d_u_2 | a002 |
| d_u_2 | a002 |
| d_u_3 | a003 |
| d_u_1 | a001 |
| d_u_3 | a003 |
| d_u_2 | a002 |
| d_u_3 | a003 |
| d_u_1 | a001 |
| d_u_2 | a002 |

Any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `DENSE_RANK()` here:

```
SELECT 'd_u_' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tenantid) AS varchar(12)) AS userid,
       tenantid
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dense_rank` function to generate this id:

```sql
SELECT 'd_u_' + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tenantid ORDER BY tenantid) AS userid,
       tenantid
FROM   mytable
```